# Регулярное выражение с диапазоном от 1 до 150

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Никак не могу понять как сформулировать регулярное выражение с диапазоном чисел от 1 до 150.

1 - 999 - `^([1-9][0-9]{0,2}|999)$`

1 - 50 - `(^[1-9]{1}$|^[1-4]{1}[0-9]{1}$|^50$)`

1 - 100 - `^[1-9]{1}$|^[1-9]{1}[0-9]{1}$|^100$`

А вот от 1 до 150 не могу сообразить...
Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: В ваших регулярках необязательно в каждом варианте писать `^` и `$`, а также ставить `{1}` (тогда в 3 скобки ещё поставить надо)

Comment: Вот тут - http://gamon.webfactional.com/regexnumericrangegenerator/ и https://www.richie-bendall.ml/ros-regex-numeric-range-generator/ и https://www.myregextester.com/index.php - можно сгенерировать, что хотите.

Answer (score 5):

Вот так вот:

```
^([1-9]\d?|1[0-4]\d|150)$
```

Тест https://regexr.com/5d79p

```
1
15
123
150
149
001
01
0
151
200
```

Answer (score 2):

```
^(00[1-9]|0[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)$
```

001 - 150

```
^(([1-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-4][0-9]|150)([,-](?=\d)|$))+$
```

1 - 150

Comment: Не от 001, а от 1.

Comment: Эникейщик исправил.

Comment: А зачем символы `,` и `-`? Про это ничего не говорится в вопросе